# Does a huge div take longer to load/use more resources than tiling divs?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am currently making a site that has one HUGE div that will be able to be scrolled around.  This div is about **1.5m px wide** by **2.5m px tall**.

It currently loads quick enough.  It has a very simple repeating tile background.

The questions are:

Which takes longer to load and which is more of a resource hog (will either way bog down a computer?)

1. A single gigantic div
2. Large divs that tile and are added and taken away depending on their position relative to the window

Are there more bytes per empty pixel in a huge div being taken? or is it negligible?

Comment: why don't you use Chrome or Firefox profiler and find out? :)

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 I haven't ever tried.  How would I go about that?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/heap-profiling

Comment: *I think* a single gigantic div will load faster because it uses less code, you should test to be sure.

Comment: @TiagoMarinho That's my general gut feeling as well.  Which I would be fine with!

Comment: Large elements should load faster than a lot of smaller ones